# strptime unable to resolve timezone value +02:00

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I am unable to resolve value `+02:00`

Below works fine with time zone `-0500` :

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-0500','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(result)
```

2017-01-12 14:12:06-05:00

Does not work fine when time zone is `-05:00` :

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-05:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(result)
```

2017-01-12 14:12:06-05:00

Answer (score 2):

Time zone in format `-05:00`, i.e. with a colon, is not supported by the `datetime` module.

But you can use `dateutil.parser` or `pandas`:

```
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

x = '2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-05:00'

res1 = parser.parse(x)
res2 = pd.to_datetime(x).to_pydatetime()

print(res1)  # 2017-01-12 14:12:06-05:00
print(res2)  # 2017-01-12 19:12:06
```

Comment: Thank you from instant reply!

Comment: @AlgirdasJarošas, No problem. Feel free to accept (tick on left) if this helped.

Comment: I am new here, but i will tick once i am allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), for the `%z` format specifier:

```
UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM
```

If I run your second example in my Python shell (Python 3.6.5), I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-05:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Based on that, offsets with `:` in are not valid. You can have to handle this yourself, or use another parsing library

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your datetime string adheres to the ISO 8601 format. I used in a similar case the method datetime.fromisoformat(date_string) and it works:

```
your_date = '2017-01-12T14:12:06.000-05:00'
parsed_result = datetime.fromisoformat(older_date)
print(parsed_result) # datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 12, 14, 12, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)))
```